# Load Image Preview Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am working on a module (In Codeigniter)  where the user Uploads an image. He has a privilege to see the preview of the image on how its is going to be displayed. I thought of doing this by ajax.

```
      1. Is is necessary to upload the image (ie save image in our database , get the url where it is stored and Load the image) to load the preview of the image.

      2. Is there any other way through which I can display the preview without storing the image in our database. (Getting the url from the client side  and displaying it.. How to do this ? )
```

Answer (score 0):

Upload the image in your asset folder and insert the path of the image in table. When you want to preview the image then give the link into image tag ( `<img src="path of the image from table" />` ) .

Comment: Ya ... Its like I want to show the image without uploading it in database. Is it possible to do so ?